# Reading date in a format from excel irrespective of systems date format using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading records from excel and inserting it in databases. There are date fields in the excel. I have given the functionality such that the user can define the format of date in excel that he is uploading.
  Consider a case where user specifies the date in excel to be as dd/mm/yyyy , Now suppose there is a date in excel such as  2/5/1993. Ideally the date should be read as 2 May 1993, but apache poi in my case is reading as 5 feb 1993 because the systems date is set to be in MM/dd/YYYY. Is there any way to tell apache POI to accept date format irrespective of the machines date format. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI has a DateFormatConverter class, which formats a date in excel using the specified pattern of certain Locale.

Comment: Thank you @mike, but I am struggling with the local class used in DateFormatConverter.convert . I used Locale local=new Locale("en", "in"); but it gives me the current date.